# Powershell script to iterate all site collections and set another quota template

Tags: powershell

I have a site collection with inside of it alot of sub site collection for each mysite instance. I would like to create a powershell foreach script which will set a quota template to each site collection. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is your question?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use a quota template, you need to have it's GUID to be able to use it in the following second script. The other method would be to use `-MaxSize` and 
`-WarningSize` attributes, which is usually what you use quota for.

Either you use the following script with the attributes:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://portal

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        Set-SPSite -Identity $SPSite.url -MaxSize 4000000 -WarningSize 2000000
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Or if you have a reference to the QuotaTemplate use the following script:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://portal

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        Set-SPSite -Identity $SPSite.url -QuotaTemplate "12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef"
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

> A quota template defines a space limit, the type of quota (hard or soft), and (optionally) a set of notifications that will be generated automatically when quota usage reaches defined threshold levels.
>
> By creating quotas exclusively from templates, you can centrally manage your quotas by updating the templates instead of replicating changes in each quota. This feature simplifies the implementation of storage policy changes by providing one central point where you can make all updates.

---

*References:*

- *[Create a Quota Template](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725711.aspx)*
- *[Set-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958.aspx)*

Comment: what do I need to set in "<Template>" ?

Comment: @KHA Preferrably a GUID referenceing the QuotaTemplate you want to use. Se my edited answer for more information.

Comment: Please respond how to get GUID of the QuotaTemplate? I am not able to get, search alot. Please help